# No gradient defined for operation MaxPoolWithArgmax in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanna use `max_pool_with_argmax` operation in TensorFlow, but I got following error:

> LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'MaxPoolWithArgmax_1' (op type: MaxPoolWithArgmax)

Here is a piece of my code that I am using `max_pool_with_argmax`:

```
BN_relu13 =   tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.batch_normalization(h_conv13,batch_mean13,batch_var13,tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64])),tf.Variable(tf.ones([64])),epsilon)) 
#max pooling 
h_pool1, argmax_1 = max_pool_2x2(BN_relu13)
```

and here is `max_pool_2x2` module:

```
def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

and after I built my network I am using `AdamOptimizer` to train my network.

By the way, when I am using `tf.nn.max_pool` (instead of `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax`) everything is working fine.

I am running my code on GPU and I am using python 2.7 on ubuntu14.

Thanks, Ali

Comment: Not every TF function has a gradient defined yet. There was one somewhere used for fancy numpy-style indexing that didn't have gradients. You may just have to use something else.

Comment: I thought because this function has been defined in neural network library, so it has to have a gradient. Do you have any suggestions how can I calculate indices of max pooling in TF? or any other function?

Comment: Are there any easy ways to check if a gradient is defined for a given tf op?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient op is actually implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc#L1316), but somehow not registered [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py#L399).  Would be worth filing a github issue on it.

At the same time, you can register the op by yourself following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/) (only the gradient registration part).

Comment: Thank you Yao. I will try it.