# How register tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanna use tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax in tensorflow, but it seems its gradient is not registered [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py#L399), while it has defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc#L1316). I am trying to register it myself from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/), but it is a little hard for me to follow what they are doing. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384167/no-gradient-defined-for-operation-maxpoolwithargmax-in-tensorflow) is my previous post about my problem with tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax)

So, does anyone any idea how I can register it in more simple way? or can anyone give me any idea about the concept of registering op in tensorflow?

thanks,

Ali

Comment: Did you checked this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1793

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found register op for ma pool with arg max there. Then I just copied that piece of the code to nn_grad.py file in tensorflow directory. It seems it is working! but I didn't check its gradient is correct or not. By the way thank you.

Comment: No problem, if you do check the gradient and find some discrepancy report back to tensorflow github